# Identifying branch commit using Azure DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

when using Azure DevOps API to show commits on a given branch, is there a way to identify commits only made from the branch by the developers and exclude merges commits from master?  My goal is to compile a list of files the developers modified within the branch and exclude any file that were rebased/merged from master.  Thanks.